# C++ function std::pow() returns inf instead of a value

Tags: c++, c++11, std, cmath

I've got a problem with returned value by `std::pow()`. Basically, I have following line in the code:

```
#include <cmath>
int main()
{
     double rate = 1.0033333333333334;
     int m = 360;
     unsigned int period = 1;
     double res = std::pow(rate, -(m-period+1));
}
```

And res has a value of `inf`. However, when I paste `std::pow(rate, -(m-period+1))` to Visual Studio watch while debugging it has a proper value of `0.30179586515268314`. Does anyone know what's the source of this discrepancy?

See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec78c5172cf53e03

Comment: [Works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb5b00b434e332fb).  Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @NathanOliver That's a lot of headers for a `std::pow` :D.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm lazy and I just keep a "header" of common includes. ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver Have you considered `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`? *\*ducks\**

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, I do not want to become cannon fodder :)

Comment: `std::pow(1.0033333333333334, -360)` -- That line of code has 1) no semicolon, and 2) the return value of `pow` is not assigned to anything.  So exactly how is that line of code used in your program?  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Cannot reproduce on g++ 8.2.1.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I just wanted to show the core of the problem avoiding unnecessary stuff like variables etc. After simplification, the problem comes down to the provided code

Comment: @SebastianKucharzyk -- That's not how it works here on SO.  The code you posted is not a [mcve].  It doesn't take long to have 2 `#include` statements, an `int main()` and a single `cout` of the value.  Note how at least 2 persons did the work you're supposed to have done.

Comment: are u using float or double? Try to use double. I am getting the correct result with both of them.

Comment: @SebastianKucharzyk well obviousy this is not the core of your problem because none of the commenters can reproduce your problem. That is why you should provide a valid example so others may spot other mistakes which lead t this strange behaviour. Also pow does not seem to return `inf` under any circumstances so where do you get this value from?

Comment: @SebastianKucharzyk I guarantee you that the problem does not come down to that line since the function returns the proper result with both g++ 8.2.1 and Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Ok, sorry guys, I will remember to provide better explanations in the future ;). Now the example is complete.

Comment: You are negating an `unsigned int` in the call to `pow`.  Of course if you stuck `-360` directly in the call, it would come out correct.

Comment: @SebastianKucharzyk  Just to let you know, the code you finally posted *did* [duplicate the issue for me](https://www.ideone.com/TATM9M).  See how valuable a full, but minimal example is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem comes from the `-(m-period+1)` part of your call to `pow`.  `period` is declared as

```
unsigned int period = 1;
```

so when

```
-(m-period+1)
```

gets evaluated you have

```
   -(int - unsigned int + int)
== -(unsigned int)
```

so you get `360` as an `unsigned int` and when you negate it, it wraps around and becomes a very large number (`4294966936` for a 32 bit `int`).  That means you are doing

```
1.0033333333333334 ^ 4294966936
```

not

```
1.0033333333333334 ^ -360
```

You need to make `period` an `int` to get the correct results.

---

If you have a number that must not be negative, don't use an unsigned type.  Nothing about `unsigned` stops negative numbers, it just turns them into a positive number.  If you want to make sure a number isn't negative, use a signed type and an if statement.

Comment: I think you got me by a few seconds.

Comment: @SebastianKucharzyk better than a "thank you" comment, you can clic the checkmark under the answer score to accept it.

Comment: @YSC, yup, I clicked but I don't have enough reputation yet. I guess it will be added to you when I will gain some more points